# Spring Cloud Gateway and Springdoc OpenAPi integration

Tags: spring, cloud, openapi, gateway

I was able to integrate Spring Cloud Gateway with the Springdoc OpenAPI in an small application with an architecture oriented to microservices. But now, when I open the Swagger UI to test the endpoint of my controller (StudentController) I realized that the @RequestMapping at the root level of the controller is not included in the URL of the endpoint to test.
The routes definition are the following:

```
routes:
  - id: students-service
    uri: lb://STUDENTS-SERVICE
    predicates:
      - Path=/students/**
    filters:
      - RewritePath=/students/(?<path>.*), /$\{path}
  - id: openapi
    uri: http://localhost:${server.port}
    predicates:
      - Path=/v3/api-docs/**
    filters:
      - RewritePath=/v3/api-docs/(?<path>.*), /$\{path}/v3/api-docs
```

And the StudentController is the following:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1")
@Tag(name = "Students")
public class StudentQueryController {

    @GetMapping("/message")
    public String dummyGet() {
        return "Student Service Dummy GET";
    }
}
```

In the Swagger UI I expected to get the URL like "http://localhost:8060/students/api/v1/message", but I got "http://localhost:8060/api/v1/message".

Someone would be kind to help me with this issue, please?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

If you have the springdoc configured in an application behind a proxy like Spring Cloud Gateway you should configure this property in your service application:

`server.forward-headers-strategy=framework`

> This property was introduced in spring-boot 2.2.0.

**Explanation:**

When the request passes through the Spring Cloud Gateway some proxy-related headers will be added to the request (like `x-forwarded-host`, `x-forwarded-proto`, etc).

With this property set your application will use those headers to make the right redirect. Instead of redirecting to `/api/v1/message` it will redirect to `/students/api/v1/message` (since the `/students` prefix will be available in the `x-forwarded-prefix` header).

> Only use this setting if the proxy behind all your applications configures correctly those headers and you can trust this proxy.
>
> If you restrict all your applications to be accessed only through the Spring Cloud Gateway you will be fine.

You can read more about this parameter and behavior [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto.webserver.use-behind-a-proxy-server).